# Android Studio and Go?

Tags: go, android-studio

Can you use Android Studio for Go development? I am able to install the gaoling plugin, but can not start a Go project?

Thanks

Comment: BTW this is not what you asked, but IMHO, you are better off using LiteIDE, which is Go specific. It's not as powerful an IDE as IDEA but it works much better with the Go ecosystem. I hope the Go plugin for IntelliJ will continue progressing and get as good, because it's an amazing platform.

Comment: Currently there is no Android Studio integration for Go, but it is in our roadmap to land a proper plugin to support Go mobile builds.

Comment: @BurcuDogan currently the Go plugin for IntelliJ platform, which is compatible with Android Studio, doesn't support the gomobile platform build as a target but I guess this could be requested https://github.com/go-lang-plugin-org/go-lang-idea-plugin/issues/new or contributed :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct answer is: Follow the instructions from the readme and the plugin will work with Android Studio: https://github.com/go-lang-plugin-org/go-lang-idea-plugin#pre-release-builds

If you have any issues, please feel free to open a ticket. Thanks.

Comment: I tried using it but it always keeps complaining about `Project SDK is not defined`. It is also not able to find imports and keeps importing the same package on `Alt+Enter`. Any suggestions or settings we need to do ?

Comment: Ok was able to fix it. We need to add the SDK along with existing Android ones. As well as add the Gopath explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

IntelliJ with golang plugin is a good choice for golang development but it doesn't support debugging, so if you want to debug with GDB then Eclipse with golang plugin is preferred.

Comment: Please note that the Go documentation states that debugging with GDB is not in a very good shape https://golang.org/doc/gdb and your answer has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: My answer is just recommendation and actually besides GDB you cannot find any powerful debug tool for Golang, right?

Comment: There's delve, which makes progress every day, https://github.com/derekparker/delve . There was also a talk about it at GopherCon 2015 so you can have a quick look there. But also, recommending a tool that's not working without the right disclaimer is not a good answer imho.